# C# Use Process.Start with parameters AND spaces in path

Tags: c#, process, path, arguments, spaces

I've seen similar examples, but can't find something exactly like my problem.

I need to run a command like this from C#:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "cmd";
startInfo.Arguments = "/K D:\\as df\\solver\\Swag.Console.exe -f D:\\as df\\solver\\2035.swag -p 5555";
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

does not work.

```
startInfo.Arguments = "/K \"D:\\as df\\solver\\Swag.Console.exe\" -f D:\\as df\\solver\\2035.swag -p 5555";
```

does not work.

```
startInfo.Arguments = "/K \"D:\\as df\\solver\\Swag.Console.exe\" -f \"D:\\as df\\solver\\2035.swag\" -p 5555";
```

does not work.

```
startInfo.FileName = "\"D:\\as df\\solver\\Swag.Console.exe\"";
startInfo.Arguments = " -f \"D:\\as df\\solver\\2035.swag\" -p 5555";
```

so it works, but I want to CMD, is this possible?

[image]

Comment: I need to CMD window was not closed after the end of the application

Comment: `var proc = Process.Start(startInfo);
proc.WaitForExit();`

Comment: _italic_ **bold** `proc.WaitForExit();`

Comment: unfortunately does not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The /K argument will execute the command that follows it. It can be a whole lot of commands chained with & but, and this is what you were missing in your attempts, they need to be fully enclosed in double quotes in that case. See [the SS64 cmd reference](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)

In other words, the command should look like this:

```
cmd /K " here what ever you want to execute"
```

Because of the forward and backslashes you quickly lose track. So I took out the outer double quotes wrapping a String.Format, so it becomes a bit more clear what your actual command should be like. Here is the code that I expect should work:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "cmd";
startInfo.Arguments = String.Format(
    "/K \"{0}\"", 
    " \"D:\\as df\\solver\\Swag.Console.exe\" -f \"D:\\as df\\solver\\2035.swag\" -p 5555");
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

If Swag.Console.Exe would simply dump its arguments to the console this would be the outcome:

> ```
> -f
> D:\as df\solver\2035.swag
> -p
> 5555
> ```